# spring-cloud-config in docker-compose https certificate not found

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, microservices

I am writing spring cloud application my config service point to my repository. In my development machine everything is working properly but when I create the docker with the help of docker-compose, my virtual machines give the following errors:

```
2017-02-28T03:14:10.847459300Z 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.JDKHttpConnection.getResponseCode(JDKHttpConnection.java:98) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:196) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:489) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:311) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1201) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:203) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:136) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.6.0.201612231935-r.jar!/:4.6.0.201612231935-r]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:399) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:373) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:358) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:177) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:155) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:132) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:42) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:53) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:145) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

I assume that I my config cannot access the https certificates. How to compose the image with yaml to tell the docker about the ssl certificates?

Answer (score 0):

First, you’ll want to create a directory where you can hold the docker compose yaml file and the ssl certificates.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── ssl
    ├── cert.key
    └── cert.pem
```

In the docker-compose.yml mount the volumes inside the container something like this and copy the cert:

```
version: '2'

services:
  image: hub:application-service
    volumes:
      - ./ssl:/etc/ssl
```